# Entity Framework First() does not return any records

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I am having issues with entity framework. The following code does not return anything:

```
Warehouse warehouse = dbcontext.Warehouses.First();
```

But if I add a break point and mouse over Warehouses I can browse records of the table, but First() doesn't return anything. In the Immediate Window if I try warehouse.Name I get the error "The name warehouse does not exist in the current context."

The table has around 10,000 records, could this be causing any issues?

edit: I have tried:

```
int count = dbcontext.Warehouses.Count();
```

and the result was 0.  This is after I was able to mouse over dbcontext.Warehouses and view records from the table. I removed the breakpoing then displayed the result on a webpage and it also displayed 0.  So it isn't something I just saw while debugging.

Comment: Are you at a point in the code where `warehouse` is valid (such as in the method where it is defined)?

Comment: I have a break point on the line below the code above.

Comment: can you post a bit more of your code and point at what point are you trying to inspect warehouse variable?

Comment: @Jason - `First` will throw an exception if it can't return a value, so `warehouse` has to have a value if there is one to return. The 'does not exist in the current context' error you're experiencing is typically related to doing *something* wrong while debugging.

Comment: @Jason - Again, `First` will throw an exception if the collection is empty (that is what `FirstOrEmpty` is for). Is it not doing this? If the collection simply doesn't contain the records you're expecting then you may want to verify the connection string is pointing to the database you expect and if that doesn't work use a sql profiler to prove what is *actually* happening under the covers.

Comment: I know it is connecting to the database because I can view the records when I mouse over dbcontext.Warehouses. Could something be timing out? I have been trying to figure out the problem for hours, but nothing seems to make sense.

Comment: What sql provider are you using here?

Comment: System.Data.EntityClient

Comment: @Jason - I've never hit this problem with the `EntityClient`. Something else must be wrong.

Comment: random, but i've heard of people that hit this when one version was pointing at another version/copy of the database.  I'd try .Take(10).ToArray() and see what you get from that.  Also, run SQL Server Profiler against the database (filtering as necessary) when doing it and check the sql run.  If you have Ultimate, use Intellitrace.  Download the trial from efprof.com is another option.

Comment: another common point of confusion is when the EF model is in a different assembly than the entry assembly - the connection string gets pulled from the entry assembly (so, app.config for an exe, web.config for webapp), not the app.config of the class lib that has the EF model

Answer (score 0):

If you are inspecting your variable just below the line where warehouse is declared, and you receive error that warehouse doesn't exist in the current context, it might happen that your debug info is not ok. Try to clean/rebuild your project and run Debug configuration. If you still receive the same error, then you are really out of scope of that variable when you try to inspect it's value.
After your edit: check your connection string, it might happen that you are pointing to a wrong database. Also, check out source for your entity classes, it might happen that Warehouses is not pointing to a table you think it points to. Also, have you tried dbcontext.Warehouses.Select(w=>w).First() ?